# Unable to kill process, even with root. How to diagnose?

Tags: bash, process, kill, background-process

There are a lot of `bash` processes running on my Ubuntu Linux (12.04). Even when I close the terminal they are still shown in the `System Monitor`.

I tried killing them as below, but they remain as it is. How to diagnose the issue, why can't they be terminated?

```
user$ ps aux | grep bash
user    2807  0.0  0.0   9484    56 pts/20   Ss+  Mar18   0:00 /bin/bash
user    4431  0.0  0.1   9228  5616 pts/7    Ss   10:39   0:00 bash
user    4655  0.0  0.0   4372   844 pts/7    R+   10:45   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.svn bash
user    5664  0.0  0.0  12764    12 pts/6    Ss   Feb05   0:01 /bin/bash
user    5812 99.6  0.1  11276  7088 ?        Rs   Sep22 3923:00 bash
user    6174  0.0  0.0  13016    28 pts/19   Ss+  Feb13   0:04 /bin/bash
p        10964  0.0  0.0  11700    28 pts/2    Ss+  Feb11   0:01 bash 
p        11126  0.0  0.0   7952   560 pts/3    Ss+  Feb11   0:00 bash 
user   18195  0.0  0.0  17320   344 pts/9    Ss+  Apr22   0:29 /bin/bash
user   21721  0.0  0.0  15924     4 pts/10   Ss+  Feb01   0:10 /bin/bash
user   22915  4.7  0.3  19400 13056 pts/22   Rs+  Jul29 3950:07 /bin/bash
user   24030  0.0  0.0  13740     4 pts/23   Ss+  Mar24   0:15 /bin/bash
user   29787  0.0  0.1   9220  5572 pts/11   Ss+  Sep23   0:00 /bin/bash
user$ 
user$ pkill -f bash
pkill: 10964 - Operation not permitted
pkill: 11126 - Operation not permitted
user$ sudo pkill -f bash
user$ 
user$ ps aux | grep bash
user    2807  0.0  0.0   9484    56 pts/20   Ss+  Mar18   0:00 /bin/bash
user    4431  0.0  0.1   9228  5616 pts/7    Ss   10:39   0:00 bash
user    4660  0.0  0.0   4372   844 pts/7    R+   10:45   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.svn bash
user    5664  0.0  0.0  12764    12 pts/6    Ss   Feb05   0:01 /bin/bash
user    5812 99.6  0.1  11276  7088 ?        Rs   Sep22 3923:21 bash
user    6174  0.0  0.0  13016    28 pts/19   Ss+  Feb13   0:04 /bin/bash
p        10964  0.0  0.0  11700    28 pts/2    Ss+  Feb11   0:01 bash 
p        11126  0.0  0.0   7952   560 pts/3    Ss+  Feb11   0:00 bash 
user   18195  0.0  0.0  17320   344 pts/9    Ss+  Apr22   0:29 /bin/bash
user   21721  0.0  0.0  15924     4 pts/10   Ss+  Feb01   0:10 /bin/bash
user   22915  4.7  0.3  19400 13056 pts/22   Rs+  Jul29 3950:29 /bin/bash
user   24030  0.0  0.0  13740     4 pts/23   Ss+  Mar24   0:15 /bin/bash
user   29787  0.0  0.1   9220  5572 pts/11   Ss+  Sep23   0:00 /bin/bash
```

Comment: What does ```kill 29787``` do? What about ```kill -9 29787```?

Comment: @MatthiasDiener sorry, didn't see the comment earlier. I rebooted PC and now the problem is gone. I had tried killing by PID but it didn't work (i think it gave no output on terminal)

Comment: First you need to stop those bash processes then kill it. Also make sure you should either be the owner of the process or a privileged user to kill a process.

Comment: @user13107, No output in the terminal means that it worked. Even when `pkill` does not work, `kill -9` should most definitely work when running as root.

Comment: @peschke be careful. No output means it did not result in an error. Whether or not it worked is an entirely different matter.

Comment: Have you tried `killall bash` ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the "unkillable" bash processes are running as user `p`:

```
user    6174  0.0  0.0  13016    28 pts/19   Ss+  Feb13   0:04 /bin/bash
p        10964  0.0  0.0  11700    28 pts/2    Ss+  Feb11   0:01 bash 
p        11126  0.0  0.0   7952   560 pts/3    Ss+  Feb11   0:00 bash 
user   18195  0.0  0.0  17320   344 pts/9    Ss+  Apr22   0:29 /bin/bash
```

You're running as user `user` so you cannot just kill any processes of user `p`.

If you have `sudo` access, you could issue the kill commands either as root or as the `p` user. For things that might be old user sessions, using `kill -HUP` would be better than just `kill`, as it allows things like editors to save a backup of any unsaved work before exiting. Also, interactive shell processes (i.e. old sessions) can be immune to a regular `kill`, but `kill -HUP` works just fine for them.

To issue the kill command as user `p`:

```
user$ sudo -u p kill -HUP 10964 11126
```

or by using root power:

```
user$ sudo kill -HUP 10964 11126
```

For processes running as user `p`, a kill command issued as user `p` will be just as strong as a kill command issued by root: even regular users have complete power over the life and death of any process they own themselves.

Comment: I'm noticing that there is a `bash` process using 99.6% of a CPU in the output of `ps` in the question. This may be the one that they want to actually terminate. It doesn't terminate though (and no other `bash` process seems to die either).  I've voted to close the Q as unreproducible/problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Do not you think that you can not kill bash in your system? You run an application/program in bash and you can kill a program that runs in bash. Now you find all processes ID programs that run in bash. 
as you showed on your terminal:

> ```
> > user    4660  0.0  0.0   4372   844 pts/7    R+   10:45   0:00 grep
> > --color=auto --exclude-dir=.svn bash
> ```

---

Try to kill that process:

```
sudo kill 4660
```

or

```
sudo kill  -9 4660
```

let me know what happeens